# How do I export .c file using Clion, I need it to be in a timeshare terminal

Tags: c, clion

I have written code for an assignment using Clion. First of all I am having trouble with run configurations using in.txt and having output to out.txt. I figured if I can't figure that out I should try testing through the terminal but I don't know how to export my .c project. There is an option to export via HTML but that configuration will not work on the terminal. If any clarification is needed lmk!

This is for a Clion Windows 10 version. This is one of our first assignments in C so I have been primarily using Eclipse for java purposes. I also couldn't figure out Eclipses C version, even just to create a new C project.

in.txt
abc h63 8ur-)(*&yhq!~ `xbv
JKL*()#$$%345~!@? >

then upon doing % charType in out, the file out will contain the lines:
out.txt: 
line 1 contains:
12 alphabetic characters: abchuryhqxbv
3 numeric characters: 638
8 punctuation characters: -)(*&!~`
5 whitespace characters:
line 2 contains:
6 alphabetic characters: JKLmnb
3 numeric characters: 345
13 punctuation characters: *()#$$%~!@?><
2 whitespace characters:
line 3 contains:
10 alphabetic characters: afsteyYDNC
2 numeric characters: 64
1 punctuation character: &
6 whitespace characters:
line 4 contains:
9 alphabetic characters: hfdjstreL
1 numeric character: 9
8 punctuation characters: *&^^%$":
1 whitespace character:

Comment: You don't export your project, you locate its files and cipy them over, manually. I suggest avoiding IDEs altogether at the initial stage of learning. An IDE introduces an element of magic to your workflow and you don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

The program you describe will probably be a single .c file, so I suppose you should be able to locate it on your drive after having created the file in C lion (I am not familiar with the tool but I suppose something like right click -> find in Explorer or some similar option should exist). If you want to export the executable, you will need to find the build location. According to [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823089-How-to-change-CLion-build-location) it seems to be somewhere in `/Users/YOU/Library/Caches/clion11/cmake/generated/` by default.

You can specify Build Output path on the Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake tab.